# "No module named 'torch'" using crontab

Tags: python-3.x, pytorch, cron, nvidia-jetson-nano

My Python code works fine if I run it from the command line by:

```
 $ python3 detect_people_main.py
```

Now I want to run the code from crontab using:

```
@reboot sleep 30 && /usr/bin/python3 /home/pip/Downloads/yolov7/detect_people_main.py >> /home/pip/Downloads/yolov7/logfile.log 2>&1 &
```

while printing the logs in `logfile.log`. But the code does not work from crontab. And the log is :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pip/Downloads/yolov7/detect_people_main.py", line 6, in <module>
    import torch
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'torch'
```

I am using Jetson NANO to run the code. Any suggestions to solve the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was running the code on reboot using crontab from the sudo user. Somehow my Python from sudo user could not find Pytorch. After switching from `sudo crontab -e` to only `crontab -e` I solved the issue for Pytorch.